# Estruturas de ordenação, porque a representação é feita em matriz?

Tags: algoritmo, estrutura-de-dados

Estudando sobre métodos de ordenação, percebi que mesmo o método recebendo um vetor, a sua representação gráfica do funcionamento e explicação do método em muitos materiais é utilizando uma matriz.

Como no exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[(referência)](http://homepages.dcc.ufmg.br/~cunha/teaching/20121/aeds2/sorting-intro.pdf).

Isso tem haver com a facilidade de explicação do funcionamento ou é porque a estrutura quando esta realizando as comparações e movimentações trata o vetor como matriz?! Confesso que fiquei confuso, alguma explicação?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isso apenas **parece ser uma matriz, mas não é**.

Cada linha é o **estado do vetor** no passo x da ordenação. Ou seja, a posição de cada elemento no array em determinado passo do algoritmo.

Essa representação é para mostrar o passo a passo do algoritmo à medida que ele vai sendo executado.

No exemplo que você deu ele está ordenando as letras da palavra EXEMPLO utilizando o algoritmo de seleção. Os elementos em destaque são os que estão sendo utilizados pelo algoritmo em cada linha

Comment: Obrigado, de fato ando meio cansado não tinha percebido isso hehe